# Is there any verse declaring Maa Parvati or Maa Durga as supreme goddess?

Tags: durga, parvati

Can anyone provide me the verse which indicates Maa Parvati as supreme Goddess?

Comment: I recommend you reading Shiv Puran you will find your answer there and you will be able to know a lot about her.

Comment: The Devi Bhagavatham is dedicated to describing Devi as the supreme goddess.

Answer (score 3):

Yes **Devi Bhagvatam** mentions so -

> 9-73. The Devas said :-- “O Auspicious One! Thou art the only Cause of this Illusion of this world, presenting an unreal appearance. So Thou art the Lady of all the beings. So, Obeisance to Thee, the S’âkambharî! Hundred-eyed! O Auspicious One! Thou art sung in all the Upanisadas; The Destroyer of the Durgama Asura! We bow down to Thee, the Lord of Mâyâ, the Dweller in the five sheaths Anna, Rasa, etc. **We meditate upon Thee, the Lady of the universe, as demonstrated by Pranava Aum, whom the chief Munis meditate with their Nirvikalpa hearts. Thou art the Mother of the endless crores of universe! Thou assumest the Divine Bodies at times for our welfare! Thou art the Mother of Brahmâ, Visnu and others; we bow down to Thee with all our heart.**

The above was said for Parvati you can find the entire things here -
https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/db/bk07ch28.htm

Comment: No, my name is not Shashwat.

Answer (score 2):

In [Mahabharata](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-mahabharata-mohan/d/doc116920.html) Devi Durga was called as supereme goddess and greater than all deities by Vaishampayan and Yudhishthira.

> he began to praise mentally the Divine Durga, **the Supreme Goddess of the Universe,** born on the womb of Yasoda, and fond of the boons bestowed on her by Narayana, sprung from the race of cowherd Nanda, and the giver of prosperity,

> It is for this, O you that hast slain the Mahishasura, that **you are praised and worshipped by the gods for the protection of the three worlds. O you foremost of all deities,** extend to me your grace, show me your mercy, and be you the source of blessings to me.

Answer (score 1):

There are plenty of verses in various scriptures that declare Bhagvatī Durgā as the supreme Goddess. For instance,

> O Aṃbikā, you are the devotion, faith and Śakti (‘energy’) of those who worship you. You are the cause, the supreme fame, peace, control, skill and forbearance (incarnate). You are the only one having the universe as your form (i.e. omnipresent) though you are called by different names.You have employed us in the various offices according to the achievements befitting our Tapas (‘penance’). You have split the enemy. You shone as Śiva, worthy of being known. O Spouse of Śaṃbhu, this wicked demon Mahiṣa has been cut down and killed.

- Skanda Purāna Maheshwar Khand

> I salute the Goddess who is omnipresent, eternal, for whom there is no support, who is never distressed, who is the mother of the three deities, who is the grossest of the gross and yet has no form.
> O Goddess of the devas, you are Perfect knowledge, Supreme Bliss, identical with the supreme Soul. Be pleased. Grant me the fulfilment of my task. Obeisance to you.

~ Shiva Purana

Answer (score 1):

There are countless verses across Puranas which Describe Devi as Supreme. Some are listed down below.

[image]
[image]
[image]

> **~ Brahma-Vaivarta Purana, Prakriti Khanda Chapter 66**

Sri Krishna Praises Durga here as with the epithets of Isvari, Para-brahma swaroopa, nirgunaa, nirasrayaa, parataparaa etc. All epithets of Para Brahman.

[image]

> **~ Kurma Purana, Purva Bhaaga, Chapter 12.**

Parvati is Described here as 'Parameshvari' , Supreme Goddess who is the soul of all and is the refuge of those who desire Moksha.

[image]

[image]

> **~ VAmana PurAna, Chapter 56**

Goddess Durga is praised here as the 'Hari-hara Rajya Dayini' (The bestower of empires to even Vishnu and Shiva) as well as 'Hari-hara-bhaskara-nute' (The one whom even Shiva, Vishnu and Surya bow to.)

In the Harivamsha, Lord Vishnu praises Durga as the supreme Goddess as well. She is also praised there as brahmavidyA and has been described as liberation itself.

> **satyaM brahma cha divyaM cha dvaipAyanavacho yathA |||2-3-31**
> According to dvaipAyana (vyAsa), you are truth (satyam), brahmA and
> divine (divyam).
>
> **vidyAnAM brahmavidyA tvamo~NkAro.atha vaShaT tathA | nArINAM pArvatIM
> cha tvAM paurANImR^iShayo viduH ||2-3-23**
>
> Among all kinds of knowledge, you are spiritual knowledge
> (brahmavidyA). You are Om and vaShaT (mantra for homa for devA-s).
> Among women, the sages know you as pArvati, celebrated in purANA-s.
>
> bhaginI baladevasya rajanI kalahapriyA | AvAsaH sarvabhUtAnAM niShThA
> cha paramA gatiH ||
> 2-3-10 You are the sister of baladeva. You are the
> night. You are fond of strife (kalaha). **You are the abode, death and
> liberation of all beings.**

> **~ Harivamsa, Vishnu Parva, Chapter 3**

In the Brahmanda Purana, Bhadrakali, A Form of Parvati has been eulogised by ParasurAma as the supreme Goddess.

> नमोस्तु ते शङ्करवल्लभायै जगत्सवित्र्यै समलङ्कृतायै ॥ २,३९.३५ ॥
>
> नानाविभूषाभिरिभारिगायै प्रपन्नरक्षाविहितोद्यमायै । दक्षप्रसूत्यै
> हिमवद्भवायै महेश्वरार्द्धङ्गसमास्थितायै ॥ २,३९.३६ ॥
>
> काल्यै कलानाथकलाधरायै भक्तप्रियायै भुवनाधिपायै । ताराभिधायै
> शिवतत्परायै गणेश्वराराधितपादुकायै ॥ २,३९.३७ ॥
>
> परात्परायै परमेष्ठिदायै तापत्रयोन्मूलनचिन्तनायै ।
> जगद्धितायास्तपुरत्रयायै बालादिकायै त्रिपुराभिधायै ॥ २,३९.३८ ॥
>
> 35b-36. Prayer: “Obeisance to you the beloved of śaṅkara, to the
> mother of the universe, to the goddess with different kinds of
> ornaments, to the goddess moving about on lion, to the one who always
> endeavours to protect those who retort to her, to the daughter born of
> Dakṣa, to the goddess born of the Himavān, to the goddess who occupies
> half of the body of Maheśvara.
>
> 37. Bow to Kālī, to the goddess who holds a digit of the Moon—i.e. the crescent moon—the lord of the digits, to the beloved of the devotees,
>     to the sovereign of all the worlds. To the goddess invoked by the name
>     ‘Tārā’[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NU7a9.png) (the redeemer), to the goddess eagerly attached to Śiva, to
>     the goddess whose sandals are worshipped by the leaders of Gaṇas.
> 38. **To one who is greater than the greatest, to the bestower of boons on Parameṣṭhin (i.e. god Brahmā), to the goddess who is thinking
>     about the ways of annihilating the three types of Tāpas (distresses),
>     to the goddess who has hurled the three Puras for the welfare of the
>     universe, to the goddess named Tripurā and (who has assumed the form
>     of) Bālā etc.**
>
> **~ Brahmanda Purana, Upodghāta-pāda ,Chapter 39**

According to Narada Purana:

> **ब्रह्मा विष्णुः शिवो गौरी लक्ष्मीर्गणपती रविः ।। पूजिताः सकला देवा यः कालीं पूजयेत्सदा ।।**
>
> One who has worshipped Goddess Kali has
> worshipped all Gods Including BrahmA, Vishnu, Shiva, Gauri , Lakshmi
> Ganapati and Surya.
> **~ Narada Purana , Poorvaardha, Chapter 85.**

Answer (score 1):

> **बीजमन्त्रजपाद्ब्रह्मा ब्राह्मीं शक्तिमवाप्तवान्** ।। तदंबायै नमस्तुभ्यं महावीरायै नमोनमः ।। २३ ।।
> **जप्त्वा सप्तशतीं विष्णुर्वैष्णवीं शक्तिमाप्तवान्** ।। तदंबायै नमस्तुभ्यं महालक्ष्म्यै नमोनमः ।। २४ ।। प्रणवास्तनया
> यस्यास्तुरीयपुरुषप्रिया ।।तदंबायै नमस्तुभ्यं प्रणवायै नमोनमः ।। २५ ।।।
> **यया दृश्यमिदं जातं यया वै पाल्यते जगत् ।।यस्या देहे स्थितं विश्वं तदंबायै नमोनमः** ।। २६ ।। शची सिद्धिस्तथा मृत्युः प्रभा गीर्वाणसैनिकाः
> ।।स्वाहा च निर्ऋती रात्रिर्ऋद्धिर्भुक्तिस्त्वदुद्भवा ।। लोकपालप्रिया
> त्वं हि लोकमातर्नमोनमः ।। २७ ।।तृष्णा तृप्ती रतिर्न्नीतिर्हिंसा
> क्षांतिर्मतिर्गतिः ।। निंदा स्तुतिस्तथेर्ष्या च लज्जा त्वं हि नमोनमः
> ।। २८ ।।**इत्यष्टकप्रभावेण क्षत्रसिंहो महीपतिः ।। शिवलोकं गतः साधु
> र्वैतालत्वमवाप्तवान्** ।। २९ ।।तस्मात्त्वं विक्रमादित्य भज दुर्गां
> सनातनीम् ।।
>
> **By Chanting Bija Mantra of Devi, Brahmaa Attained his Braahmi Sakti. By Chanting her Saptasati, Vishnu Attained his Vaishnavi Shakti.** I
> salute that Amba, Mahalaksmi who is the mother of Pranava and who is
> dear to the Tureeya-Purusha and who is herself the form of Pranava. I
> salute that devi through whom the entire world is visible, through
> whom it is sustained and in whose body it is situated. Sachi, Siddhi,
> Mrtyu, prabhaa, Kartikeya , Svaaha, Raksasas, Ratri, Riddhi and Bhukti
> are all born of her.You are dear to Lokapala and Lokamata. You are
> Trishna, tripti, Rati, Niti, Himsa, Kshanti, Mati, Gati, Ninda, stuti,
> Irshya and lajja.**By chanting this Octet, King Kshtrasimha Attained
> Shiva-loka. Hence, O Vikramaditya! You must worship that Sanatani
> Durga!**

**- Bhavishya PurAna, Pratisarga Parva khanda-2, Chapter 22**

> **संसारतापत्रयदावदग्धाः, शरीरिणो यौ परिचिन्तयन्तः। सद्यः परां
> निर्वृतिमाप्नुवन्ति, तौ शंकरौ मे शरणं भवेताम्।। १०८.१०५ ।।** आर्ता ह्यहं
> पीडितमानसा ते, क्लेशादिगोप्ता न परोऽस्ति कश्चित्। देव त्वदीयौ चरणौ
> सुपुण्यौ,तौ मे शरण्यौ शरणं भवेताम्।। १०८.१०६ ।।
> **ययोः सकाशादिदमभ्युदैति, प्रयाति चानते लयमेव सर्वम्। जगच्छरण्यौ जगदात्मकौ तु, गौरीहरौ शरणं भवेताम्।। १०८.१०७ ।।** यौ दववृन्देषु
> महोत्सवे तु, पादौ गृहाणेश(ति)गिरीशपुत्र्याः। प्रोक्तं धृतौ
> प्रीतिवशाच्छिवेन, तौ मे शरण्यौ शरणं भवेताम्।। १०८.१०८ ।।
>
> 112-113. Let Śāṅkarī and Śaṅkara be my refuge. **Meditating upon those
> two deities, the embodied beings who have been scorched by the forest
> fire of the three types of worldly distresses, attain the greatest
> beatitude immediately.**
>
> I am distressed. My mind has been afflicted. There is no one other
> than you to protect me from suffering, distress etc. O lord, your feet
> are extremely meritorious and worthy of being sought refuge in. Let
> them be by my refuge.
>
> **114-115. Gaurī and Hara are worthy of being sought refuge in by the entire universe. They are the immanent souls of the universe. This
> entire (visible universe) rises from, prospers in and finally merges
> with those two deities.** Let them be my refuge.
>
> In the course of a great festival Devas said, “O Īśa, touch and hold
> the feet of the daughter of the lord of mountains”. As soon as this
> was said they were lovingly held by Śiva. Let those two feet be my
> refuge. They are worthy of being sought refuge in.

**- Brahma Purana 2(38)**

Answer (score 1):

**Yes. Here are some such verses where Ma Parvati is verily described as the Supreme Goddess**

### Nārada Purana, Uttarabhaga, 73. 136-141

> 136. **I bow down to this Uma who is the daughter of  Mena, who cannot be comprehended, who is full of splendour,  who cannot be measured**
>      and who makes her breasts whitened  by means of the Bhasman at the
>      time of embracing her  beloved lord.
> 137. **I bow down to Uma, who is resplendent, whose  refulgence of limbs is magnet-like inaction and whom Hari,  Brahma and Indra bow
>      down to**. She is the goddess who  stays near Girisa (Siva) and
>      surveys the worlds.
> 138. I salute this daughter of Mena whose pastime is  the protection of the wretched ones; who bestows honour and  bliss; who is master of
>      the lores and the auspicious  words and who makes use of affable and
>      courteous words for  propitiation.
> 139. **O Bhavani, O goddess Sivā who dispels the great  fear of distress of worldly existence**, whose sole pleasure is  your
>      ornaments, grant us an excellent intellect free from  hindrances
>      whereby we shall cross all evils.
> 140. **O Sivā, where and how can your equality be  extended to ? The creation of the universe is your sport; Siva  is your husband, Hari is
>      your servant; Indira (Laksmi) is your  maid-servant. So also are Saci
>      and Sarasvati**. You are the for¬  tunate (blessed) bestower of
>      wealth.”

### Skanda Purana, Kāśī-khaṇḍa, Uttarārdha, Chapter 72

> 37. **Obeisance to you, O goddess, the nursing mother of the universe, the source of origin of the three worlds (like the Araṇi producing
>     fire), O great Śaktì of Maheśvara**, O destroyer of Daityas, like an axe
>     felling trees.
> 38. **O śivā pervading the three worlds, O wielder of conch-shell, discus and club, obeisance to you in the form of Viṣṇu engaged in
>     holding forth in your hand your own Śārṅga bow.**
> 39. Obeisance to you, O goddess with the swan for vehicle, O creatress of all.created things. O ground of origin of all worlds without
>     beginning, O goddess in the form of the Four-faced Lord.
> 40. **You are the Śakti of Indra, of Kubera, of Vayu (the Wind-god), of Varuṇa, of Yama, of Nirṛti, of Īśa and of Fire-god.**
> 41. **You are the light of the Moon; you are the Śakti of the Sun; you are the Śakti of all the gods; you are the supreme goddess.**
> 42. You are Gaurī; you are Sāvitrī; you are Gāyatrī; you are Sarasvatī. You are Prakṛti; you are the (cosmic) intellect; you are in
>     the form of the great Ego.
> 43. You are in the form of the mind; you are in the form of all Indriyas (sense-organs). You are in the form of the five Tanmātras
>     (subtle elements); O Aṃbikā, you are in the form of all (gross)
>     elements.
> 44. You are in the form (of the qualities like) sound etc. You are one who blesses all the organs of action; you are the creator of the
>     Cosmic Egg, O goddess. You are identical with the Cosmos.
> 45. **O great goddess, you are the supreme goddess; you are greater than the greatest; you are in the form of the supreme soul, greater than
>     everything beyond.**
> 46. O Īśānī, you are in the embodiment of everything; you are the formless one; you are present everywhere. O great Māyā, you are the
>     power of Consciousness (Cicchakti). O immortal one, you are Svāhā; and
>     also Svadhā.
> 47. You are in the form of Vaṣaṭ and Vauṣaṭ; **you are in the form of Praṇava; you are in the form of all the Mantras; Brahmā and others are
>     born of you.**
> 48. **You are in the form of the four aims of life; you are the outcome of the benefit of the four aims of life; this entire universe is
>     (born) from you; O storehouse of the universe, everything is in you.**
> 49. **Whatever is visible and invisible, whatever is gross and subtle you are in the form of Śakti therein. There is nothing anywhere
>     without you.**

Answer (score 0):

Maa Durga as the Brahman.:

> 3-6. I am the five elements as also what is different from them. I am the entire world. I am the Veda as well as what is different from it. I am the unborn; I am the born. Below and above and around am I. I move with Rudras and Vasus, with Adityas and Visvedevas. Mitra and Varuna, Indra and Agni, I support, and the two Asvins. I uphold Soma, Tvastir, Pusan and Bhaga, The wide-stepping Vishnu, Brahma, Prajapati. To the zealous sacrificer offering oblation And pressing the Soma-juice do I grant wealth; I am the state, the Bringer of Wealth; Above it all, place I its protector.
>
> 28. Beyond Her is nothing; renowned is she as Durga; feared of life,I bow to Durga, Bulwark against all sins; the Pilot who Steers me across the sea of worldly life. (Devi Upanishad).

I hope this clarifies all your queries. Prd..

Answer (score 0):

> **57.O Viśveśvarī (goddess of the universe), you are the creator of the people of all the worlds; you are the protectress and the
> destroyer at the time of the ultimate annihilation.** The river of
> great pure merit arising out of the repetition of thy names dispels
> all the sins as though they were the trees on its banks.
>
> **58. O mother Bhavānī, O destroyer of the entire collection of the fierce miseries of worldly existence, you alone are the refuge. There
> is no one else**. Only they are blessed in all the worlds, only they are
> worthy of honour, they, in whom your splendid glance of mercy falls
> and shines.
>
> 59. Those who remember you always, you who have the innate brilliance, who are stationed in Kāśī, who constitute the glory of salvation unto
>     those who bow down, are remembered by Lord Smarahara (‘Destroyer of
>     the god of Love’) as the people of pure intellect and clever and
>     deserving to have salvation and protection.
> 60. **O mother, if anyone retains in his heart the pair of your feet free from impurities, the entire universe is within the grasp of his
>     hands.** If, O Maṅgalā-Gaurī, anyone repeats your name everyday, the
>     eight Siddhis never leave his house.
> 61. **O goddess, you are of the form of Praṇava, the mother of Vedas; you are Gāyatrī;** you are the wish-yielding cow of the twice-borns.
>     You are the three Vyāhṛtis (Bhūḥ, Bhuvaḥ and Svaḥ) here for the
>     fulfilment of all Karmas. You are Svāhā, the giver of the satisfaction
>     to Devas, and Svadhā, the giver of satisfaction to Pitṛs.
> 62. O Goddess, O mother, you are Gaurī in respect to the Moon-crested Lord; you are Sāvitrī in respect to Vedhas (Brahmā); you are the
>     charming Lakṣmī in respect to the Discus-bearing Lord Viṣṇu. **O
>     fine-featured goddess, you, the glory of salvation in Kāśī, O
>     Maṅgalā-Gaurī, you are my refuge.**

[~ Skanda Purana, Kasi khanda(PURVARDHA), Chapter 49](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-skanda-purana/d/doc423787.html)

The Above stuti is for Parvati from Skanda purana where she is the Supreme Goddess.

> **अमरपतिमुकुटचुम्बितचरणांबुजसकलभुवनसुखजननी ।। जयति जगदीशवंदिता सकलामलनिष्कला दुर्गा ।। ११ ।।**
>
> I Salute Durga whose feet are kissed by the crown of Suresa (Indra),
> Who bestows pleasure to all the worlds, Who is Worshipped even by
> Jagadisvara (The Lord of the Universe), who is both sakala and niskala
> (with and without parts.)
>
> **~ Bhavisya Purana, uttar parva, Chapter 61**