# Has each member of the family of Siva - Siva,Parvati,Ganesa,Kartikeya been called Brahman?

Tags: shiva, brahman, family

For Siva we have numerous examples.  For Kartikeya we have a reference from Mahabharata.  How about Ganesa and Parvati?

Comment: Parvati has a whole Purāṇa I.e. Devi bhagavata purana considered as the supreme Brahman mother of jada chetana, etc. As far as Ganapati goes, Adi Shankara says one the five forms of Brahman are: Shiva Vishnu Brahma (or Surya), Devi and **Ganesha**

Comment: Ganapati Atharvashirsha.

Comment: why has  this question has been closed?  It is a place-holder to add more citations for all the deities concerned.  It is a nice tag to direct google searches here there might be citations for the family taken together @the destroyer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question is actually duplicate of a set consisting of the following questions,

1. [Which Vedic verses depict Lord Shiva/Rudra as the Brahman?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/19831/which-vedic-verses-depict-lord-shiva-rudra-as-the-brahman)
2. [Is there any verse declaring Maa Parvati or Maa Durga as supreme goddess?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/43869/is-there-any-verse-declaring-maa-parvati-or-maa-durga-as-supreme-goddess)
3. [Which scriptures portray Lord Ganesha to be the supreme God?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/21542/which-scriptures-portray-lord-ganesha-to-be-the-supreme-god)
4. [Do any scripture portrays Lord Kartikeya (Murugan) to be the Supreme God?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/21549/do-any-scripture-portrays-lord-kartikeya-murugan-to-be-the-supreme-god)

In any case, the answer is Yes.